# Get Fatal error when installing slim 3 framework

Tags: php, composer-php, slim

I was installing slim 3 according to **[Slim Documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/start/installation.html)**.After installing i have created **index.php** file.Given below:

**index.php:**

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Slim\App();

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $response->write("Hello, " . $args['name']);
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

But when i run the application in http://localhost:8000 then i get a fatal error.I have searched and get some solution in stackoverflow.Those are:

- [PHP Fatal error: Class 'Slim' not found - Slim Framework 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834950/php-fatal-error-class-slim-not-found-slim-framework-3)
- [PHP Fatal error: Class 'Slim' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369302/php-fatal-error-class-slim-not-found)
- [Composer autoloader + slim framework - fatal error: Class 'Slim\Slim' not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27826936/composer-autoloader-slim-framework-atal-error-class-slim-slim-not-found)

But those solution does not solve my problem.Have any specific solution of it?

**ERROR:**

> Fatal error: Class 'Slim\App' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\api\index.php on line 5

And my directory format:

[image]

**UPDATED:**
*vendor/autoload.php:*

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit98cfb2e091de2f633f87c81d16402aec::getLoader();
```

*vendor forlder:*
[image]

Comment: what is your fatal error ??

Comment: Show what's in your vendor dir, and show what's in vendor/autoload.php.

Comment: Do not put your index.php into the vendor folder, it is for dependencies only.

Comment: @Drudge Now 1 added fatal error in question.

Comment: @MikaTuupola I do not put `index.php` file into vendor folder.

Comment: @ksimka see, i updated question.

Comment: Looks like `slim` itself is missing in your vendor folder. Did you do `composer require slim/slim "^3.0"` or something else?

Comment: @ksimka yes i do `composer require slim/slim "^3.0` this.and move the Slim folder into directory which include example,vendor and Slim folder and some file as mention first picture.

Comment: Why do you move something? When you move `slim` folders, you break an autoload structure. Just use as is.

Comment: @ksimka Now i have done as it is in your way but it says page not found.What page not found?

Comment: Try `http://[your-site]/name/John`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102445/discussion-between-chonchol-mahmud-and-ksimka).

Comment: @ksimka when i give localhost:8000/name/john then it says again page not found but when i try localhost/api/name/john then it says object not found.

Comment: I can see that you have put your index.php into vendor/slim/slim/ the root folder of your project should contain only vendor folder and index.php. Not any other files.

Comment: Try with `index.php` i.e. `http://localhost:8000/api/index.php/name/john`.

Comment: Nope.I put index.php file in htdocs/api directory not in htdocs/api/vendor/slim directory.

Comment: @Tpojka Its says "not found" in the server.

Comment: dont understand why down vote?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have downloaded and extracted Slim manually into `htdocs\api\Slim`.

It wasn't fetched by Composer, then it would reside in the vendor folder (`vendor/slim/slim`) and the autoload would work automatically.

---

Add Slim to your `composer.json` and run `composer install` again:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

You already require the Composer Autoloader, so the depenendency should be found and loaded after it was fetched.

Referencing: http://docs.slimframework.com/start/get-started/

Comment: Slim 3 does not have autoloader anymore. Only way is to use Composers autoloader.

Comment: Ok, i removed the solution for Slim 2.